Why is Grails throwing 'Could not prepare statement' error after upgrade from 3.2.6 to 3.3.5?
We recently upgraded our Grails project from 3.2.6 to 3.3.5, after which we began receiving intermittent errors indicating the the connection had already been closed when using the builtin domain class methods such as the findBy, findAllBy, save methods.
We do not received this error every time these methods are called, but rather they seem to happen after a random number of instances have been called.
We seem to be able to resolve the issue if we wrap the call to these domain methods in a withTransaction closure, but would prefer not to go through the whole application to track down all calls to these domain class methods and wrap them in this closure.
In case it is relevant, we the project is configured with multiple datasources. The domain classes which are causing this error use the default dataSource.
Does anyone know why this has started happening, did something change between Grails 3.2.6 and 3.3.5 which would require us to start making all domain class calls within  transaction? If so, is there a way to prevent this need?
Stacktrace:

2024-07-12 11:21:02.198 ERROR --- [io-7080-exec-85] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection has already been closed.
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.listForCriteria(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:719)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.list(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:709)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.invokeQuery(FindAllByFinder.java:54)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder$1.doInSession(FindAllByFinder.java:48)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:42)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.doInvokeInternal(FindAllByFinder.java:45)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:254)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:392)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FinderMethod$invoke$2.call(Unknown Source)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:181)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6163.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)

application.yml:
    production:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                url: "jdbc:mysql://<<URL>>?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                driverClassName: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                username: "<USERNAME>"
                password: "<PASSWORD>"
                pooled: true
                properties:
                    jmxEnabled: true
                    initialSize: 5
                    maxActive: 50
                    minIdle: 5
                    maxIdle: 25
                    maxWait: 10000
                    maxAge: 600000
                    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                    validationQuery: 'SELECT 1'
                    validationQueryTimeout: 3
                    validationInterval: 15000
                    testOnBorrow: true
                    testWhileIdle: true
                    testOnReturn: false
                    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)
                    removeAbandoned: true
                    removeAbandonedTimeout: 60
                    dbProperties:
                        autoReconnect: true
            second:
                url: 'jdbc:as400://<URL>;transaction isolation=none'
                autocommit: true
                pooled: true
                username: "<USERNAME>"
                password: "<PASSWORD>"
                driverClassName: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
                properties:
                    jmxEnabled: true
                    initialSize: 1
                    maxActive: 50
                    minIdle: 1
                    maxIdle: 25
                    maxWait: 10000
                    maxAge: 600000
                    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                    validationQueryTimeout: 3
                    validationInterval: 15000
                    testOnBorrow: true
                    testWhileIdle: true
                    testOnReturn: false
                    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)
                    removeAbandoned: true
                    removeAbandonedTimeout: 60

